# HTTP Server - how to change the response URL?

Tags: java, http

I have a HTTP server implemented using purely API from sun and would like to change the response header (HttpExchange).

What must I write so that the response URL is different?

For example, when I go to http://somewhere.com/roar.html, the response would be the HTML in roar.html, but the address bar would show http://somewhere.com/.

Please note that there is a system constraint here: the implementation should be in Java SE.

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIR The only way to change the browser/client address is to send a redirect.

Comment: take request as http://somewhere.com/ and then forward your request to http://somewhere.com/roar.html,

Answer (score 0):

You should take request as `http://somewhere.com/` and then **forward** that request to `http://somewhere.com/roar.html`.So that your address bar will not change

Comment: Hello, how do I do that with Java SE? Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me the forward thing is in Java EE.